# WebFlux web and webflux starter

Tags: spring-webflux

I created a `Spring boot 2.0.0.M7` project with the `webflux starter` because I want to use all the asynchronous and the non-blocking capabilities.
I added the `server.servlet.context-path` but it does not work if I don't add the web starter as well.

If I add both starters can I have issues with the non-blocking functionality?
I executed some stress tests with Gatling and I have received the same scores removing the web starter or adding it.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 5):

If you add both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` to your application, Spring Boot will configure it as a Spring MVC app.

This is intentional as many Spring MVC will get the webflux dependency to leverage the new `WebClient` in their MVC apps. Also, as of Spring Framework 5, Spring MVC knows how to handle a few cases with Flux at the controller level.

You can always force your choice like this:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
app.run(...);
```

In your case, this is not about forcing a choice but rather using something that's not supported in WebFlux.

The `server.servlet.context-path` configuration property is Servlet-specific, so it won't work with WebFlux. Currently Spring Boot does not support war deployment nor multiple web contexts for WebFlux applications. So there's no point in offering such a property.

The runtime model difference between "Servlet-based" and Reactive runtime with Spring can be quite subtle, and I encourage you to watch a [talk that describes those choices](https://content.pivotal.io/springone-platform-2017/servlet-or-reactive-stacks-the-choice-is-yours-oh-no-the-choice-is-mine-rossen-stoyanchev). The short answer is: if you're using Spring MVC with async types (`DeferredResult`, `Flux` or `SseEmitter`) things will be async but reading and writing will still be blocking.

Properly benchmarking that is quite hard, but the results you're seeing are somehow expected. Running locally server+client, no latency involved, looking at raw throughput - all of those constraints should not be in favour of the reactive model which has a concurrency cost. If anything, this benchmark shows that the reactive stack is quite optimized already, even for non-ideal use cases!

Comment: @Brain Clozel , With your explanation after making changes in main method app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE); it started working . but my springbootTests are not working. How to make it available?

Comment: Could you create a new question for that? I'm sure other people are facing the same issue. Thanks!