# Difference between spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux?

Tags: spring-boot

I tried including one of said dependencies at the time but I can't find any difference:

- spring boot starter web: I can see Flux and Mono classes and make a reactive rest controller
- spring boot starter webflux: I can see rest controller classes and annotation and I can make a canonical rest controller

So, what am I missing? Using spring boot 2.2.5-RELEASE.

Comment: `Spring Web` uses `Tomcat` as default embedded container and `Spring Reactive Web` uses `Netty`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case: I switched to spring-boot-webflux and logs still say that tomcat is brought up

Comment: it should... webflux : `Netty started on port(s): 8080` and web : `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`

Comment: Unfortunately not :( And what's more flux works with tomcat as well

Comment: are you using `spring-webflux` or `spring-boot-starter-webflux` as dependency?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-webflux

Comment: ... then Netty should be used and not Tomcat, but anyways as vicpermir answers, there is an overlap of spring web and webflux...so yes you can use Flux and Mono in a normal Controller.

Answer (score 8):

If you check the official documentation there is a small section that, I think, should answer your question:

### [1.1.4. Applicability](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-framework-choice)

> Spring MVC or WebFlux?
>
> A natural question to ask but one that sets up an unsound dichotomy. Actually, **both work together** to expand the range of available options. The two are designed **for continuity and consistency** with each other, **they are available side by side**, and feedback from each side benefits both sides. The following diagram shows how the two relate, what they have in common, and what each supports uniquely:
>
> [image: mvc and webflux venn]

You can even add both and it will default to a regular Spring MVC web application but will let you use the new `WebClient` introduced in Spring 5. This behaviour is described, among other places, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux):

> Both web frameworks mirror the names of their source modules (spring-webmvc and spring-webflux) and co-exist side by side in the Spring Framework. Each module is optional. Applications can use one or the other module or, **in some cases, both — for example, Spring MVC controllers with the reactive `WebClient`**.

I'm not an expert on this but, like you, I was curious about the shared bits of both and the reasoning behind it. You can find more information here:

- [Does not the starter-web and starter-webflux work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51378560/1031296)
- [WebFlux web and webflux starter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47835851/1031296)